# How to progmatically change the ImageView image in a textview?

Tags: android, image, textview

When I have a TextView with a left/right image, how can I change that at runtime? I've googled a bit and found a lot about doing it via XML, but not much on doing it in code. This is what I tried, but this changes the entire textview background. I'm trying to just change the imageview contents.

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newimage);
Drawable d = iv.getBackground();
textView3.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Comment: Done.  Apologies - forgot about doing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind—this does it.

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redbg);
Drawable d = iv.getBackground();
d.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
tv3.setCompoundDrawables(d, null, null, null);
```